# How to create a webcrawler in scrapy to fetch .mp3 links

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to make a webcrawler that can fetch .mp3 links from a website. However the content is dynamic in the example site http://raagtune.net/ . In this site the content is fetched from **"http://raag.me//music/data/.. some random .mp3"** how can we crawl the entire site and get all MP3 links using scrapy in python? Or is there any alternative methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `beautifulsoup` package of python.

`import httplib2
 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.nytimes.com')`


`for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print link['href']`

Just check whether that  URL has `.mp3` in that link. If yes, store it in list else continue.

Hope this helps !